# Kendo Mobile (Appending kendo js files using javascript doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, kendo-mobile

I'm trying to append kendo mobile resources files dynamically then initialize Kendo mobile application but the problem seems to be kendo mobile resources did not successfully loaded when I'm trying to initialize the application. Here is my code.

Config.js :

```
function initKendoResources(){

                    var element;
            var jsFilesList = new Array();
            jsFilesList[0] = 'resources/kendosdk/jquery.min.js';
            jsFilesList[1] = 'resources/kendosdk/kendo.mobile.min.js';
            jsFilesList[2] = 'js/viewmodel/LoginViewModel.js';
            jsFilesList[3] = 'js/viewmodel/HomeViewModel.js';
            jsFilesList[4] = 'js/viewmodel/NotesViewModel.js';
            jsFilesList[5] = 'js/stores/Notes.js';
            jsFilesList[6] = 'js/common/GlobalData.js';
            jsFilesList[7] ='customers/attune/js/common/Labels.js';
            jsFilesList[8] ='customers/attune/js/viewmodel/HomeViewModel.js';

            for(var i in jsFilesList){
            element = document.createElement('script');
            element.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
            element.setAttribute('src',jsFilesList[i]);
            document.head.appendChild(element);
            }



}
```

In my Html bodyOnLoad I call this function here is my html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo App</title>

<link id="kendocss" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/common/Config.js"></script>


</head>
<div data-role="view" id="splash">

</div>
<body onLoad="initKendoResources();">


</body>

<script>

   App.application = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);


</script>
</html>
```

But it gives me kendo is not defined... I tried callback approach ass well but didn't work please help

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to dynamically load reference files? Have you looked at requireJS ?

Comment: Hi Whizkid747 it is due to my project requirement. Thanks I'll give it a try

Comment: This will help get you started: http://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2012/11/30/making-a-well-structured-kendo-ui-mobile-app-in-icenium-with-require-js/